# How to remove encryption in Marshmallow without root?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, encryption

Encryption is making transferring of files from phone to PC really slow besides I want to open my phone without any prompt and jump directly to my work.

As far as what I've tried is to go to settings but nothing occurred on tapping encryption.
As my phone is in warranty and and also not popular (Eluga Tapp) root not seems to be a viable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A factory reset will remove the encryption. After doing this you might want to install a custom recovery, just in case. There are many tutorials to do this in the internet.

Comment: Is custom recovery specific to phone or is universal as my phone model as a rare sight?

Comment: Usually twrp has  recoveries for almost any phone, but don't flash one for another phone, they are specific. Usually tutorials provide a link. There are also other recoveries, but I like twrp best.

Comment: But it's not the case with my phone :(

Comment: What phone do you have? Maybe there is some unofficial recovery project. Even my opx has a custom recovery at twrp

Comment: My model is Panasonic Eluga Tapp and XDA search gives no solved post.

Comment: Ok at least it seems like there is some custom recovery for this phone. Here a link to a tutorial, but for your first flash at a phone from this brand I would recommend searching for a second tutorial, just to be sure how this works. koselas.com/how-to-install-twrp-custom-recovery-on-panasonic-eluga-tapp/

Comment: Such websites are often dubious which enlist post for every model existing ever to gain views.

Comment: That's why you usually look it up on other sites, too.

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit  more?

Comment: Ok I really did not find anything, but maybe you know a bit more about your device, for example my Nexus 7 2012 was called grouper, so you could look around and find the "real" name, if you dont know and look it up at [here](https://twrp.me/Devices/) But it could be a thing that your phone has not a name like this. Because my Oneplus X for example was just called "onyx", wich was quite obvious if you have bought it.